# Каким образом можно настроить отправку результатов fitnesse-тестов из jenkins на определённый endpoint в определённом JSON-формате?

Tags: json, юнит-тесты, test-automation, jenkins

Приветствую!
Есть такая задача: необходимо отправлять результаты прохождения Fintesse-тестов для проектов на заданный endpoint, в заданном JSON-формате. То есть, перед отправкой их необходимо каким-либо образом обработать. В Jenkins у меня уже настроен периодический запуск fitnesse-тестов и сохранение результатов в xml-файл, вопрос в том, как теперь из этих данных сформировать JSON-файл.

Пока что есть две идеи:
1) Найти некий плагин/написать скрипт, который можно настроить в afterbuild параметрах сборки проекта. Поиск конкретного плагина пока успехом не увенчался, со сриптом тоже есть вопросы.
2) Внедрить какой-нибудь JUnit listener прямо в fitnesse-тесты, чтобы при сборке результаты собирались, формировался JSON и отправлялся в указанное место. Правда, тут уже вопрос, как определить, откуда "изнутри" Fitnesse брать результаты тестов.

Если есть какие-то идеи или предложения, буду очень признателен.

Спасибо!